# Random reboots on 14.04 desktop

Tags: reboot, crash

I've experienced many reboots at random intervals and with no stress on the machine I've found the logs and skimmed through them but I do not know what I am looking for so I cannot fix the whole thing.  I have removed the wireless PCI, changed CPU fan, removed all the case fans and now the PC runs with the bare minimum peripheral devices. The reboots have lessened but the problem has not disappeared.

How to track the cause of reboots?

Edit: from what I've seen when the PC restarts it does not show any output on the screen, the mouse and keyboard do not have power and the CPU fan spins very slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My distribution has no problem. The PSU had issues.

Hint for future visitors:

Make sure your PSU is from a recognized company and of excellent **quality**.